# Using BufferedReader to read an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, bufferedreader

I'm just beginning to learn Java, and I'm unsure of how to use BufferedReader to read an array in the assignment I'm working on. getSalesData is its own method. I understand that I need to use BufferedReader to ask the user to input a number (which are Strings here) and then store it in data [0] and [1], but I'm unsure of how to proceed and fix the errors. Any tips would be very much appreciated!

```
   String [] getSalesData (){
        String [] data = new String [2];
        String [] ticketsSold = "";
        String [] ticketPrice = "";

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String buffer = new String ();

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print ("Enter your agent ID:");
            buffer = br.readLine ();
            ticketsSold = buffer;

            br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print ("Enter your agent ID:");
            buffer = br.readLine ();
            ticketPrice = buffer;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("Invalid entry");
        }

        return data;
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I'm having problems with ticketsSold and ticketPrice. I keep getting told there's a type mismatch and the program can't convert from String to String []. I also suspect some of my array syntax may not be correct.

Comment: You are doing `br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));` twice -- you don't need to. Once you have `br` you just do `br.readLine()` each time you need it. And get in the habit of closing your streams and readers when you're done ... `br.close()` ...  (also google for `try-with-resources`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

br.readLine() will return a String and you are setting ticketsSold = buffer. So let's examine a little closer: buffer is a string and ticketsSold is an array of strings. this should produce an error for you (if you can post the error stack trace that would be very helpful). I'm not sure if you actually want ticketsSold and ticketPrice to be arrays of Strings as here it looks as if they should just be strings.

So if you want them to really be arrays of strings, use:

```
ticketsSold[0] = buffer;
```

and

```
ticketPrice[0] = buffer;
```

or you can change the declartion of ticketPrice and ticketsSold to be strings:

```
String ticketsSold = "";
String ticketPrice = "";
```

hope this helps and welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about it as I am also a beginner
but i think this should work properly

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print ("Enter your details:");//(suppose name and email)
buffer = br.readLine ();
String[] strArray = buffer.split(' ');
//then this strArray contains all the input separately
String name = strArray[0];
String email= strArray[1];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

peggy's answer already explained why you get the errors and how to resolve them. But actually you don't need `ticketsSold` and `ticketPrice` at all. You said you want to put the input in `data[0]` and `data[1]`. Therefore, completely remove `ticketsSold` and `ticketPrice` and write

```
data[0] = buffer;
```

and

```
data[1] = buffer;
```

in the appropriate locations. Then your return value will be correct.